# clear div contents but keep plain text, using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I have divs on a form:

```
<div id="foo">
<div>koko</div>
<div>lala</div>
Plain text here
<div>Another div</div>
</div>
```

I want to use jquery in order to keep "Plain text here" but not show any other internal element in the others divs.

I tried using the `.not` like this:

```
alert($("#foo).not("div").text());
```

But it doesn't display anything.

Comment: Hide all divs within the div of id="foo", what you have left is the text.

Comment: I want to process the text with javascript. Not only show it in the page. So I have to remove the divs from the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var text = $('#foo').clone().find('*').remove().end().text()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LtMHE/

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is:

```
$('#foo *').remove();​​​​​​​​​
```

The selector selects any elements within #foo, and only the text you look for will be kept.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CcH5P/)

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to remove wrapped text, maybe this will work:

```
$("#foo *").remove();
```

Am I misunderstanding your question?

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead :

```
alert($("div#foo").clone().children().remove().end().text());
```

Hope this will help !!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to get your plain text, is to use these jQuery methods -> contents() and filter().

contents [<sup>[source: doc]</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) :

> Description: Get the children of each element in the set of matched
> elements, **including text** and comment **nodes**.

So we can get both DIV and #text nodes.

filter [<sup>[source: doc]</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) :

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or
> **pass the function's test**.

In the function test, we'll keep only what we want, the text nodes (with the nodeType == 3, which is text).
So, in the end, we have:

```
$("#foo").contents().filter(function(){ return this.nodeType == 3}).text().trim();
```

(the trim() is here to not select all the line breaks in your sample, as they are text too)

**[demo js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B8KV5/)**